# Which statement will execute first in this case?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing, android-viewmodel

I have been trying to make Junit test wait for an Async task to get completed but have been stuck.
Suppose we have class like this

```
class MyViewModel{

 public void doSomething(){

    new Task(){

      void inBackground(){
         model.getData(); //Executes for 4000 ms max

      void onMainThread(){
         displayData();
      } 


    } 

 }

  void displayData(){

  } 
}
```

Here is my test method

```
@UiThreadTest
@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception{
   MyViewModel myViewModel = Mockito.spy(new MyViewModel());
   myViewModel.doSomething();
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   verify(myViewModel).displayData();          
}
```

The problem i am facing is that the `verify` statement is getting called before `displayData` in the inner class of `MyViewModel`and the test case fails. How do i solve this problem?   Any other way of testing the same functionality is also welcome.

Comment: use callback .!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using `CountDownLatch`

```
final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);


   public void someTest() throws Exception{
     MyViewModel myViewModel = Mockito.spy(new MyViewModel());
     myViewModel.doSomething();
     // It will wait either 5 secs or your countDown signal from 
     //postexecute from task
     signal.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     verify(myViewModel).displayData();          
    }
```

You should also call `signal.countDown()` from your post-execute. If you don't want to wait 5second  and yjust want to make sure that verify runs only after your complete background process than don't give any parameters in `signal.await()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a handler.

In the setUp method of the test class ,i created a handler.

```
@UiThreadTest
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    handler = new Handler();
}
```

Note that i use the @UiThreadTest annotation for the method to associate the handler with the UiThread.

In the test method , i used the handler to run the viewmodel code on the ui thread and the verify methods on a different thread. Note that i removed the @UiThreadTest annotation here.

```
@Test
public void testThatInspectionsAreFetchedWhenVesselIdIsSet() throws Exception{
    MyViewModel myViewModel = Mockito.spy(new MyViewModel());
    handler.post(() -> myViewModel.doSomething());
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    verify(myViewModel).displayData(); 
  }
```

Now the test method works perfectly!